# Embeddable distributed version control system in Java?

Tags: java, dvcs

Is there a distributed version control system (like git or Mercurial) that can be used as an embedded library in Java applications (to implement versioned and synchronizable storage for application data), ideally written in pure Java and under a permissive license?

Answer (score 4):

@Josh Moore's reply led me to [JGit](http://www.jgit.org/), which seems to be a competitor to JavaGit. JGit is pure Java and licensed under BSD.

Some further digging unearthed [HgKit](http://hgkit.berlios.de/), which aims to implement Mercurial in Java. It is still pre-alpha and GPLed.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any pure Java solutions.  But, check out http://javagit.sourceforge.net/ you can use it to connect to a git repository with Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure Java library, [SVN Kit](http://svnkit.com/) for interacting with **Subversion**

Comment: It's been a while since I've checked but I don't think Subversion supports "distributed" in the same way that Git and Mercurial do.