# How to "cat" a file in JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

A while back I was looking for an [embeddable distributed version control system in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177469/embeddable-distributed-version-control-system-in-java),
and I think I have found it in [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), which is a pure Java implementation of git.
However, there is not much in the way of sample code or tutorials.

How can I use JGit to retrieve the HEAD version of a certain file (just like `svn cat` or `hg cat` whould do)?

I suppose this involves some rev-tree-walking and am looking for a code sample.

Comment: The developers are pretty quick to answer on the mailing list : https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/egit-dev . I suggest you give it a try.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately Thilo's answer does not work with the latest JGit API. Here is the solution I found:

```
File repoDir = new File("test-git");
// open the repository
Repository repository = new Repository(repoDir);
// find the HEAD
ObjectId lastCommitId = repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
// now we have to get the commit
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository);
RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(lastCommitId);
// and using commit's tree find the path
RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create(path));
if (!treeWalk.next()) {
  return null;
}
ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(objectId);

// and then one can use either
InputStream in = loader.openStream()
// or
loader.copyTo(out)
```

I wish it was simpler.

Comment: Who in the world designed this API?

Comment: Do you know what the nth value from treeWalk.getObjectId(nth) does? (i.e. what are the cases where we pass a value to treeWalk.getObjectId  bigger than 0 ?)

Comment: @DinisCruz `TreeWalk` can walk over more than one tree (by calling `addTree` multiple times). In that case, you can use `getObjectId(N)` to get the object ID from tree N (which might the the same or different, depending on the trees).

Comment: See creinig's answer for how to simplify this a bit by using `TreeWalk.forPath`.

Comment: How can I save the output of `loader` into a variable?

Answer (score 18):

Here's a simpler version of @morisil's answer, using some of the concepts from @directed laugh's and tested with JGit 2.2.0:

```java
private String fetchBlob(String revSpec, String path) throws MissingObjectException, IncorrectObjectTypeException,
        IOException {

    // Resolve the revision specification
    final ObjectId id = this.repo.resolve(revSpec);

    // Makes it simpler to release the allocated resources in one go
    ObjectReader reader = this.repo.newObjectReader();

    try {
        // Get the commit object for that revision
        RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(reader);
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(id);

        // Get the revision's file tree
        RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
        // .. and narrow it down to the single file's path
        TreeWalk treewalk = TreeWalk.forPath(reader, path, tree);

        if (treewalk != null) {
            // use the blob id to read the file's data
            byte[] data = reader.open(treewalk.getObjectId(0)).getBytes();
            return new String(data, "utf-8");
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

`repo` is a Repository object as created in the other answers.

Comment: Looks good, except for returning getBytes() while the return type is String. Note that you also have to call `release` on `walk` and `treeWalk` for releasing resources. To have to do that only once, call `ObjectReader reader = repo.newObjectReader()` and pass that to Revwalk and Treewalk instead of the repository. Then call `reader.release()` in a finally block.

Comment: RevWalk also needs to be released, move the call to `newObjectReader` up and use `new RevWalk(reader)` instead.

Comment: Another comment (sorry :)), `this.repo.open` should also be replaced by `reader.open`.

Comment: @robinst: Fixed. And feel free to edit the answer as needed ;)

Answer (score 12):

I followed @Thilo's and @morisil's answer to get this, compatible with JGit 1.2.0:

```
File repoDir = new File("test-git/.git");
// open the repository
Repository repo = new Repository(repoDir);
// find the HEAD
Commit head = repo.mapCommit(Constants.HEAD);
// retrieve the tree in HEAD
Tree tree = head.getTree();

// 1.2.0 api version here
// find a file (as a TreeEntry, which contains the blob object id)
TreeWalk treewalk = TreeWalk.forPath(repo, "b/test.txt", tree);
// use the blob id to read the file's data
byte[] data = repo.open(treewalk.getObjectId(0)).getBytes();
```

I didn't test the Java version but it should work. It translates from

```
(.getBytes (.open repo (.getObjectId (TreeWalk/forPath repo "b/test.txt" tree) 0)))
```

in clojure (following the same setup as the top section), which does work.

Comment: Works great! I went straight to file: `FileOutputStream fileOS =  new FileOutputStream(path);
if (treewalk != null){repo.open(treewalk.getObjectId(0)).copyTo(fileOS);}` then `fileOS.close;`

Comment: More Java questions should be answered in Clojure.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out by myself. The API is quite low-level, but it's not too bad:

```
File repoDir = new File("test-git/.git");
// open the repository
Repository repo = new Repository(repoDir);
// find the HEAD
Commit head = repo.mapCommit(Constants.HEAD);
// retrieve the tree in HEAD
Tree tree = head.getTree();
// find a file (as a TreeEntry, which contains the blob object id)
TreeEntry entry = tree.findBlobMember("b/test.txt");
// use the blob id to read the file's data
byte[] data = repo.openBlob(entry.getId()).getBytes();
```

Comment: This seems to be an outdated example with the current JGit release. The API has changed a bit, beware.

Comment: @Jonathan Dumaine: Please update the post if necessary (and you know how)

Answer (score 4):

I have started writing a library called [gitective](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective) that contains many helpers for working with blobs, commits, and trees using JGit and is MIT-licensed and available on GitHub.

**Get content of file in HEAD commit**

```
Repository repo = new FileRepository("/repos/project/.git");
String content = BlobUtils.getHeadContent(repo, "src/Buffer.java");
```

**Get content of a file on a branch**

```
Repository repo = new FileRepository("/repos/project/.git");
String content = BlobUtils.getContent(repo, "master", "src/Buffer.java");
```

**Diff two files**

```
Repository repo = new FileRepository("/repos/project/.git");
ObjectId current = BlobUtils.getId(repo, "master", "Main.java");
ObjectId previous = BlobUtils.getId(repo, "master~1", "Main.java");
Collection<Edit> edit = BlobUtils.diff(repo, previous, current);
```

More examples of utilities provided are detailed in the [README](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: It looks nice.  If I hadn't already written my jGit project I would have definitely used this.

Answer (score 3):

There is some info at [JGit Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/egit/wiki/TableOfContents) (but that also is neither really helpful nor complete and probably outdated since they switched to [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) where no documentation is available yet).

Answer (score 3):

You can read the content of a given filepath as follows. Please be aware that the TreeWalk can be *null* if no path was found in the given tree. So it requires some specific handling.

```
public String readFile(RevCommit commit, String filepath) throws IOException {
    try (TreeWalk walk = TreeWalk.forPath(repo, filepath, commit.getTree())) {
        if (walk != null) {
            byte[] bytes = repo.open(walk.getObjectId(0)).getBytes();
            return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No path found.");
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
ObjectId head = repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
RevCommit last = repo.parseCommit(head);
readFile(last, "docs/README.md")
```

This answer is written with JGit 4.8.0.