# Similar Java access code (methods) of Git/JGit as SVNKit

Tags: java, git, svn, egit, jgit

I know much about SVN and accessing repositories from Java code using the [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) APIs. I am able to do these operations on SVN:

- Open a repository
- User's authentication check before accessing a repository
- Validating an SVN URL
- Get the project list under a given URL
- Export a project/file by a given revision number
- Get the latest revision of repository/project/file
- Fetch updates

Now I need to provide the support for [Git](http://git-scm.com) as well with the same functionality. I have installed Git/EGit/JGit, and I've looked at some [samples](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) as well with the JGit APIs but I'm not able to do most of the above tasks using Java code. It seems too complex for me, being an SVN user. Any guidance/help on this?

Comment: It would be worth your time to read through and understand how Git works. [Pro Git by Scott Chacon](http://git-scm.com/book) is my personal favourite.

Comment: @Sammer its a commands of Git only, I want the Java APIs for Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Sameer, you will have to get familiar with how Git works, see the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

To your list of questions, there are not always direct equivalents because the concepts are different. Hints to some of the questions:

#### Open a repository

```
File workTree = new File("/path/to/git-repository");
Repository repository = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setWorkTree(workTree).build();
```

#### Export a project/file by a given revision number

See 
[How to “cat” a file in JGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685228/how-to-cat-a-file-in-jgit)
.

#### Get the latest revision of repository/project/file

```
Git git = new Git(repository);
ObjectId head = repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
// All commits, use setMaxCount(1) for newest, use addPath for filtering to path
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().add(head).call();
```

#### Fetch updates

Use the `FetchCommand` (using `git.fetch()`) or `PullCommand`, depending on what you want, see [API documentation of Git](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html) and navigate to the commands there.

Answer (score 2):

My project [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) provides samples for many common tasks, maybe that gets you started. Also the [jgit userguide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide) explains some of basic concepts and provides samples as well. Third i would look at the [javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/) of classes which are in a fairly good state, even if the API is a bit confusion sometimes.