# JGit Traverse Local and Remote Branches only HEAD and read the files

Tags: java, git, jgit

I want traverse my git repo but only the HEAD commit including the remote branches.
I have only local master branch and a lot of remote branches.
I can traverse my actually working directory like.

```
    Ref head = repository.getRef("HEAD");
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);

    RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
    RevTree tree = commit.getTree();

    TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
    treeWalk.addTree(tree);
    treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
    while (treeWalk.next()) {
        System.out(treeWalk.getPathString())
    }
    repository.close();
```

But this code only traverse the actual working directory.
Afterwards i want read the files in the head commit.
How i perform the reading and traversing the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [RefDatabase#getRefs](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/RefDatabase.html#getRefs%28java.lang.String%29) to walk through the existing refs:

```
RefDatabase refDatabase = repository.getRefDatabase();
Map<String, Ref> refs = refDatabase.getRefs(Constants.R_REMOTES);
for (Ref remoteRef : refs) {
    // ...
}
```

The argument to getRefs is a prefix to get only certain refs, you can also use `RefDatabase.ALL` for getting all refs.

For reading the file contents, walk the tree as in the code from the question. Then, with the TreeWalk object, the contents can be read. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14856330/305973) from the [How to “cat” a file in JGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685228/how-to-cat-a-file-in-jgit) question.

Comment: I become a list of origin/branch_* and refs/remote/origin/branch_* but how i can iterate the content of the branches?

Comment: The same way you iterate over the contents of HEAD in the question. I also added instructions for how to get file contents to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this code shows me all the content but not in the right order i want.
It starts at a random remote branch.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> entry : refList.entrySet()) {
            Ref head = repository.getRef(entry.getValue().getName());
            RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
            RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
            RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
            TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
            treeWalk.addTree(tree);
            treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
            while (treeWalk.next()) {
                    ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
                    ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(objectId);
                    loader.copyTo(System.out);
            }
}
```