# Execute git commands from JGit

Tags: git, jgit

Is there anyways to execute specific git commands and get the response of execution in JGit?
It's difficult and complicated to execute following command for example in JGit

```
git show <commit>:<file path>
```

Any documentation or reference is highly appreciated. I did went through documentation but haven't found particulars.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685228/how-to-cat-a-file-in-jgit may help, and https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/